# Execute a sql query using cursor and store its value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, cursor

Not able to insert the record in table. I am using sql server trying to insert record in table after executing the query. I want to store the no of rows in the view along with the view name in a table. Getting error when trying to store the query result in the table along with the view name.

```
DECLARE @Sql  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @view_name  NVARCHAR(MAX);
Drop TABLE IF EXISTS AllTableUnion

IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.AllRecords') AND type in (N'U'))

BEGIN

CREATE table dbo.AllRecords 
(
  query varchar(MAX),
  view_name varchar(MAX)
)
END



SELECT   'select count(*)  from ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']'  as query, 
'[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']'  as view_name
into AllTableUnion
FROM sys.all_objects  AS t
where t.schema_id=1 and t.TYPE like 'V'
group by t.schema_id, t.name


DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT  query,view_name
FROM AllTableUnion  --<-- table where sql is stored   


OPEN Cur

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql, @view_name

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

  insert into dbo.AllRecords(
         query,view_name
        )
    values (Exec sp_executesql @Sql, print @view_name

     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO  @Sql , @view_name
END

CLOSE Cur

DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (That code looks more like SQL Server.)

Comment: You cannot execute dynamic sql in a values clause and you haven't explained what you are trying to do and drop table if exists does not exist in sqlserver(but it does in mysql). You seem to have mashed together two sql dialects - which are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: I am using sql server trying to insert record in table after executing the query, I want to store the no of rows in the view along with the view name in a table. Getting error when trying to store the query result in the table along with the view name.
Tried to use this method also:

Comment: How to store data from exec sp_executesql @query table along with view name also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the insert in the @sql build for example

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Alltableunion'))
    begin
        drop table alltableunion
    end
go
--create table alltableunion(query varchar(max),view_name varchar(max))
--go
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.AllRecords'))
    begin
        drop table allrecords
    end
go

DECLARE @Sql  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @view_name  NVARCHAR(MAX);
--Drop TABLE IF EXISTS AllTableUnion

IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.AllRecords') AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
        CREATE table dbo.AllRecords 
        (
        query varchar(MAX),
        view_name varchar(MAX)
        )
    END

SELECT   'insert into allrecords(query,view_name) 
select count(*),'+char(39)+'[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' + char(39) + 
' from ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']'  as query, 
'[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']'  as view_name
into AllTableUnion
FROM sys.all_objects  AS t
where t.schema_id=1 and t.TYPE like 'V'
group by t.schema_id, t.name

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT  query,view_name FROM AllTableUnion  --<-- table where sql is stored   

OPEN Cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql, @view_name
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
     print @sql
     exec sp_executesql @sql
     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO  @Sql , @view_name
END
CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur;
select * from allrecords

query       view_name
----------- ---------
5           [dbo].[vu]

(1 row(s) affected)
```

And why would you have a count set to varchar(max)?

Comment: getting error 'Invalid column name ' when I am trying to insert value from the parameter SELECT 'insert into dbo.allrecords(query,view_name,frequency) select count(*),' + CHAR(39) + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' + CHAR(39) + ', ' + @frequency + ' from ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS query ,'[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS view_name, 'old' as frequency

Comment: There isn't a column called frequency in the table allrecords - or at least there wasn't did you change the table definition? and there isn't a variable call @frequency.

Comment: I haven't provided that in the comment section but i have updated the allrecord table definition and declared the @frequecy variable as old. Now it is treating old as column name not as a value in the table